# Flutter - Syncfusion's drawImage gives error Invalid/Unsupported image stream

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

I was trying to put an asset image into a PDF document.

```
late Uint8List bmp;
if(i.contains('webp')) bmp = (await img.decodeWebP(bytes))?.buffer.asUint8List() ?? bytes;
else if(i.contains('jpg')) bmp = (await img.decodeJpg(bytes))?.buffer.asUint8List() ?? bytes;
doc.pages[0].graphics.drawImage(PdfBitmap(bmp), Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Before I caught an error

> Unsupported operation: Invalid/Unsupported image stream
> ...
> PdfBitmap._initialize (package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/src/pdf/implementation/graphics/images/pdf_bitmap.dart:193:7)

My question is, yes! obviously how to solve it.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks a lot. good to know that. i just read it from pub.dev to confirm it

Comment: Yeah, I've been yelled at previous for posting this, but I get an equal number of "oh c**p I did not know that" responses as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real culprit is [this image plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/image). I have to use `decodeWebP` to decode a `jpeg`, but it doesn't work for a `webp`. Weird.

```
Uint8List? bmp = (await img.decodeWebP(bytes))?.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Comment: @KJ thank you but sorry. the question is about pdf but the fix has nothing more to do with pdf

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize the asset image folder and provide the code snippet below as a reference for you.
Add the following code in your pubspec.yaml file.

```
    flutter:
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
```

Add the following code in the lib/main.dart file.

```
    Future<List<int>> _readImageData(String name) async {
final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('images/$name');  
return data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);  }
```

Kindly try this on your end and let us know if required any further assistance.
Refer to the KB documentation for more details.

[How to convert image to PDF in Syncfusion Flutter PDF Library? | Syncfusion](https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/10453/how-to-convert-image-to-pdf-in-syncfusion-flutter-pdf-library)

Please note that we only support PNG and JPEG image formats